# My php script has loop and take all available physical memory for unknown reason

Tags: php, loops, memory, time

I already increase my memory limit from 1 gb to 2 gb .
my php.ini file

```
memory_limit = 2G

upload_max_filesize = 2G

post_max_size = 2G

max_execution_time = 1500

max_input_vars = 10000

suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000

suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000

suhosin.get.max_value_length = 10000

suhosin.request.max_varname_length = 35000
```

But I get this error when I run my PHP script:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/givezuya/public_html/includes/system/Exceptions.php on line 47

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/givezuya/public_html/includes/Common.php on line 204
```

line number 47 in Exceptions.php :

```
if (is_cli()) {
```

line number 204 in Common.php :

```
if (isset($last_error) && $last_error["type"] & (1 | 4 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128)) {
```

Actually I want to open contact page .
the link of my contact page is : [here](https://www.giveturn.com/index.php?view=contact) .

full code of contact.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('EvolutionScript'))
    die('Hacking attempt...');
// Help desk//
$helpdesk = new \Evolution\Models\Helpdesk();
if (!$helpdesk->isOnline()) {
    redirect();
}


if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {
    $captcha = \Evolution\Components\Captcha::load('contact');
    if ($input->post('do') == 'submit') {
        $form_validation = new \Evolution\Components\Form_validation();
        if (!$user->isOnline()) {
            $form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required', [
                'required' => lang('enter_full_name')
            ]);
            $form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email', [
                'required' => lang('enter_email'),
                'valid_email' => lang('enter_valid_email')
            ]);
        }
        $form_validation->set_rules('department', 'department', 'required|is_natural_no_zero', [
            'required' => lang('select_department'),
            'is_natural_no_zero' => lang('select_department')
        ]);
        $form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'subject', 'required', [
            'required' => lang('enter_subject'),
        ]);
        $form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'required', [
            'required' => lang('enter_message'),
        ]);
        if (!csrf_validation()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidtoken');
        } elseif (!$captcha->validate()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidimageverification');
        } elseif ($form_validation->run() == false) {
            $error_msg = validation_errors();
        } elseif (!$helpdesk->validate_department($input->post('department'))) {
            $error_msg = lang('select_department');
        } else {
            $helpdesk->create_ticket();
            $session->set_flashdata('form_success', lang('ticketsent'));
            redirect(current_url());
        }
    }

    $template->display('helpdesk_open.tpl', [
        'error_msg' => isset($error_msg) ? $error_msg : null,
        'captcha' => $captcha
    ]);
}

if ($input->get('view_ticket')) {
    if ($user->isOnline()) {
        if (!$ticket = $helpdesk->getRow(['ticket' => $input->get('view_ticket'), 'user_id' => $user->get('id')])) {
            redirect('?view=contact');
        }
    } else {
        if (!$ticket = $helpdesk->getRow(['ticket' => $input->get('view_ticket')])) {
            redirect('?view=contact');
        }
        if (!$session->has_userdata('ticket_id') || $session->userdata('ticket_id') != $ticket->id) {
            redirect('?view=contact');
        }
    }

    if ($input->post('do') == 'reply') {
        $form_validation = new \Evolution\Components\Form_validation();
        $form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'required', [
            'required' => lang('enter_message')
        ]);

        if (!csrf_validation()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidtoken');
        } elseif ($ticket->status == 4) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidrequest');
        } elseif ($form_validation->run() == false) {
            $error_msg = validation_errors();
        } elseif (!$helpdesk->user_reply($ticket->id, $ticket->status)) {
            $error_msg = lang('wait_to_replyticket');
        } else {
            $session->set_flashdata('form_success', lang('msgsent'));
            redirect(current_url());
        }
    }
    $template->display('helpdesk_view.tpl', [
        'error_msg' => isset($error_msg) ? $error_msg : null,
        'ticket' => $ticket
    ]);
}



if ($user->isOnline()) {
    $template->display('helpdesk_user.tpl', [
        'pagination' => $helpdesk->user_tickets($user->get('id'))
    ]);
} else {
    if ($input->post('do') == 'view_ticket') {
        include_once BASEPATH . 'Sources/ticket.php';
        $form_validation = new \Evolution\Components\Form_validation();
        $form_validation->set_rules('ticketid', 'ticketid', 'required|alpha_dash');
        $form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email');
        if (!csrf_validation()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidtoken');
        } elseif ($form_validation->run() == false) {
            $error_msg = lang('ticket_not_found');
        } elseif (!$ticket = $helpdesk->getRow(['ticket' => $input->post('ticketid'), 'email' => $input->post('email')])) {
            $error_msg = lang('ticket_not_found');
        } else {
            $session->set_userdata('ticket_id', $ticket->id);
            redirect('?view=contact&view_ticket=' . $ticket->ticket);
        }
    }
    $template->display('helpdesk_home.tpl', [
        'error_msg' => isset($error_msg) ? $error_msg : null
    ]);
}
```

To fix the problem, I add ini_set`('memory_limit', '-1');` in my php script . After adding that i get another error like Error 503 . Service unavailable
I already told my hosting provider and they told me that:

```
It takes all available physical memory for some reason.I would advice contacting a web developer for assistance.this case requires advance knowledge in the sphere of the web development.
```

help me anyone to fix this serious issue . I already try all the possible way but can't fix this issue.

Comment: I don't know, but `if (isset($last_error) && $last_error["type"] & (1 | 4 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128)) {` looks invalid to me.

Comment: This 2 blocks of code can't create exception, because they are exception handlers, so they are just reacting to something that causes memory leak. It can be in any place of your code =)

Comment: But you can try to show us more lines from Exceptions.php and it's `is_cli` function

Comment: @Anton Kindly checkout . I already attached full Exceptions.php file with question. If you want any other code then please tell me .

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton can you check more and give me valid code?

Comment: What are you trying to do before such error happens? Open some page in browser? Run PHP code in command line? We need details.

Comment: @Anton Kindly see the question again . I update the question again with your required details only for you.  please see from "Actually I want to open contact page . the link of my contact page is : here ................"  in the question. If you need any other details then feel free to tell me because i try my best to solve this issue but i can't do that and only for this issue i can't publish my website . so this is very urgent for me . please try your best to help me .

Comment: @Anton i think the problem can be with contact.php file . please checkout the contact.php file

Comment: This part is suspicious: `if (!$helpdesk->isOnline()) { redirect(); }`, because `redirect` does not have parameter... Please try add some logs here. For example change this line: `redirect();` (seems it is line 7) to this line: `die('We are offline, sorry...');`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this line `$last_error["type"] & (1 | 4 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128))` is just an errors bitmask. Not suspicious.

Comment: @Anton sorry to say the problem is still remain. I can't fix this . Really i can't understand what happen with me .

Comment: @Anton All the other page is completely fine except support page(contact.php)

Comment: @SayeedHossain do you see this line: `die('Hacking attempt...');`? It stops script from running further. Try add this line to the top, right after `<?php` line. Your script should stop just in the beginning. Try it

Comment: @Anton i tried to add these line after <?php but the problem is still remain. Also i comment out these two line but unfortunately i can't fix this .

Comment: my hosting provide told me that , in my php script , there are some code which take all the available physical memory . it can be occurs like loop problem .

Comment: @Anton you can see my expected interface by visiting this link : http://demo.ptcevolutionscript.com/index.php?view=contact

Comment: @SayeedHossain `i tried to add these line`... Whait, what? Comment all the lines of code in `contact.php` except for `<?php`. Problem still remain? If yes, it seems you are 1) cheating us, 2) give us the wrong files, maybe check routes in your application

Comment: @Anton after Comment all the lines of code in contact.php except for <?php , the problem is fix and it shows blank white page .  And brother i didn't give you wrong file because just only for this issue i can't publish my website . I am very much serious about that . If you need more file then just tell me please . Also if you want to connect me with teamviewer or other remote control platform to help me then you can do it .

Comment: @Anton after adding " die('Hacking attempt...'); " this line right after <?php line then the problem is fix and it shows  just " Hacking attempt... " text in the page .

Comment: @SayeedHossain ok, better. So try moving this added line `die('Hacking attempt...');` 1 line lower (for example if now this command is on line 1, then move it to line 2, and so on). On some point you will find the place where this command (hacking) still visible, but on the next line - not. Find this "broken" line number.

Comment: @Anton the suspicious line is " if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {  ......" in  contact.php file . Because i follow your instruction and when i add " die('Hacking attempt...'); " this line after " if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {  ......" this line then the problem again occur. Can you please tell me what's the wrong with " if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {  ......" this line ?

Comment: Yes and no... Don't know if you are a developer, but there are 4 big `if` blocks in you contacts.php. Eash `if` can be evaluated to "true" and so all the code inside will run, or it will evaluate to "false", so this `if` will be skipped. Check the other `if`. I mean check this line: `if ($input->get('view_ticket')) {` and this: `if ($user->isOnline()) {` (also it has '} else {` about 4 lines below - this also should be checked)

Comment: The idea is to find which block of code crashes. By saying "block of code" I mean something starting with `{` and ends with `}`. So first step is to check the top-level blocks, then go inside and so on

Comment: @Anton Dear , I checked all the code in contact.php . when i add "                 die('Hacking attempt...'); " this line anywhere in every " if " statement then the error is occur but when i add " die('Hacking attempt...'); " this line outside the all " if " statement then the problem is fix . so the problem is in " if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {........} " , " if ($input->get('view_ticket')) {....} " and  " if ($user->isOnline()) {....} " code . How can i find the problem easily ? Can you please tell me some hints to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume that you have error in your first `if`.

Here I've added some `die` commands (now they are commented).

Un-comment them one-by-one. So, start with `die('1')`. If you un-comment this line, you will see "1" on your page. If so, then delete this `die('1')` command (or comment it back). And continue with the new one.

The problem is that this code has no suspicious parts, so it is hard to say exactly what block is bad - we need to find that block.

```php
//die('1');
if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {
//die('3');
    $captcha = \Evolution\Components\Captcha::load('contact');
    if ($input->post('do') == 'submit') {
//die('6');
        $form_validation = new \Evolution\Components\Form_validation();
        if (!$user->isOnline()) {
            $form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required', [
                'required' => lang('enter_full_name')
            ]);
            $form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email', [
                'required' => lang('enter_email'),
                'valid_email' => lang('enter_valid_email')
            ]);
        }
//die('7');
        $form_validation->set_rules('department', 'department', 'required|is_natural_no_zero', [
            'required' => lang('select_department'),
            'is_natural_no_zero' => lang('select_department')
        ]);
        $form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'subject', 'required', [
            'required' => lang('enter_subject'),
        ]);
        $form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'required', [
            'required' => lang('enter_message'),
        ]);
//die('8');
        if (!csrf_validation()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidtoken');
        } elseif (!$captcha->validate()) {
            $error_msg = lang('invalidimageverification');
        } elseif ($form_validation->run() == false) {
            $error_msg = validation_errors();
        } elseif (!$helpdesk->validate_department($input->post('department'))) {
            $error_msg = lang('select_department');
        } else {
            $helpdesk->create_ticket();
            $session->set_flashdata('form_success', lang('ticketsent'));
            redirect(current_url());
        }
    }

//die('4');
    $template->display('helpdesk_open.tpl', [
        'error_msg' => isset($error_msg) ? $error_msg : null,
        'captcha' => $captcha
    ]);
//die('5');
}
//die('2');
```

In the end you will have list of `die` commands that you've seen on a screen, and a list that is not worked (just for example it can be that 1,2,3 - you've seen them, but 4,5,6,7,8 - they all goes to memory crash)

Comment: I just copy-paste your code and follow your instruction . After complete all of them , i got just 1 and 2  .

Comment: @SayeedHossain shocking results I must say. Because between 1 and 3 there is a line: `if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {` And there is nothing that could use all the memory there... Of course we can go deeper into `$input` object and its `get` method, but... It is very strange all what happens

Comment: I think so . this is very strange . is there can be other problem except take all available memory? Actually i already apply almost all the method to fix " error 503 " but can't fix this .

Comment: My hosting provider is namecheap . They 100% assure me that there is no problem with cpanel configuration . So what's the problem ? what ? what? Really it is very strange .

Comment: @SayeedHossain you can try to find in your code something like `$input = `, so the place where `$input` is created. I think it is a wrapper for GET and POST parameters... So you can also try replace your `comments.php` with: `<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); echo "</pre><hr><pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: After replacing , it shows Array
(
    [view] => contact
) ...........

Comment: for better understanding please visit :  https://www.giveturn.com/index.php?view=contact

Comment: @SayeedHossain try this one: `<?php echo $input->get('t');` Maybe it will crash, maybe not

Comment: after replacing this , it didn't crash but it shows full blank white page . it didn't print anything except a blank white page.

Comment: @SayeedHossain =( so we returned to the beginning of this maze. Because if this line has error: `if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {` and this does not: `echo $input->get('t');`, then we have no directions to run

Comment: @SayeedHossain I see your page https://www.giveturn.com/index.php?view=contact is opening now (without memory error). Have you changed something?

Comment: In contact.php , now there are just '<?php echo $input->get('t');' code which you told me to add . That's why this page is opening (white blank) without memory error.

Comment: I have a question . `if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {` this code means checking/comparing text "new" with the value of `if ($input->get('t')` is equal or not . ok, now when i want to print the value of `if ($input->get('t')` code then it just shows a blank white screen instead of any text .  so my question is how is this possible to check/compare between  "blank white screen" and text "new " ? it can be the reason to create any problem ?

Comment: `echo $input->get('t')` means "show what is inside `$input->get('t')`. We see blank screen, so there is nothing inside (actually undefined, but we can treat this as an empty answer). So comparing `if ($input->get('t') == 'new') {` is like comparing empty string with "new" (that results in FALSE of course, and so this `if` won't go inside)

Comment: @SayeedHossain but you know... It is strange that 1 hour ago your site was working normal... https://img.devrant.com/devrant/rant/r_193997_oFvPt.jpg

Comment: what do you mean by normal ? normal means blank white screen ?

Comment: @SayeedHossain nope. I've seen you "contact" page working normally (a common site design with a feedback form on it). I will take screenshot next time it will be working...

Comment: this is totally impossible . Because in contact.php,there are only `<?php echo $input->get('t'); ` this line is exists. I think you checked this link : [ http://demo.ptcevolutionscript.com/index.php?view=contact ]  . This is the demo link  which i sent you to give information about my expected interface and this link is perfectly work . But my website contact page link  is : [ giveturn.com/index.php?view=contact ]  which is not work .

Comment: @SayeedHossain ok, sorry, maybe I checked the wrong site.

Comment: it's ok . by the way , someone told me that , he will fix this issue for 100 dollar . should I go to him and pay 100 dollar to fix this issue? is it really possible to fix?

Comment: @SayeedHossain all is possible to fix. Depends on time and money as always.

Comment: @SayeedHossain did you tried to contact the creators of the original site? I mean ptcevolutionscript

Comment: yes , I tried to contact with them but can't get any feedback . They just told me to contact  with my developer.  Really i am going to depression day by day for this issue .

Comment: @SayeedHossain you mean error in one of the `tpl` files? There are 3 of them in `contact`: `helpdesk_open.tpl`, `helpdesk_view.tpl`, `helpdesk_user.tpl`. Which one of them do you think have error?

Comment: @SayeedHossain and another thing: many Site content managers have cache of templates somewhere. Maybe you can clean up the cache.

Comment: I think this 4 tpl file `helpdesk_open.tpl, helpdesk_view.tpl, helpdesk_user.tpl,helpdesk_home.tpl` has no problem because i already checked this.You can try to find out is any problematic external link  added in this 4 tpl file or not .  I think some external link which can be added in this 4 tpl file can be the reason for this problem.

Comment: @SayeedHossain the same advice as before: change something to see the difference. For example try removing all (or replace with some string like "XXX") between `{block name="content"}` and `{/block}`. And see what happens then.